# How can I add a slideDown() animation to newly created elements in my Meteor/Blaze site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, meteor-blaze

I have two unordered lists that contains a set of li elements. The li elements in each unordered list are represented by an array in my backend with each li element corresponding to an item in the respective array.

When I hit the checkbox on one li element, my backend splices the item from one array and puts it into another. This effectively destroys the li element and recreates it in the other list.

I am trying to call a slide up and slide down animation for when the item disappears and reappears from on list to another. However I am only able to get the slide up animation to work when it leaves one list.

When it appears in the other list, the slide down animation does not work, the element simply pops in.

Is there any way that I can append the slideDown() animation to all newly created li elements? Would it be done through an event listener?

Here is a basic representation of what my code currently looks like:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="top-list">
       <li class="js-checkbox"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number</li>
       <li class="js-checkbox"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number</li>
       <li class="js-checkbox"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bot-list">
       <li class="js-checkbox"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number</li>
       <li class="js-checkbox"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    const target = event.target;
    let children1 = target.parentElement;
    let input = $(children1).find('.filled-in');
    var list = $(children1).parents('li');  //<li> element
    var parentList = list.parents('ul');   //<ul> element
    var parentDiv = list.parents('div'); //parent div
    var findTop = parentDiv.children("ul.top-list"); //find sibling
    var findBot = parentDiv.children("ul.bot-list"); //find sibling

     if (input[0].checked === false) {
         $(list[0]).slideUp(300, function() {
             instance.data.changed(instance.data.instruction._id.toString(), 0, true);
             $(list[0]).appendTo($(findTop[0]));
             $(list[0]).slideDown(300);
         });
     } else {
         $(list[0]).slideUp(300, function() {
             instance.data.changed(instance.data.instruction._id.toString(), 0, true);
             $(list[0]).appendTo($(findBot[0]));
             $(list[0]).slideDown(300);
         });
     }
```

Explanation of JavaScript:

If an item is being checked, it gets sent to 'top-list' and send to 'bot-list' if unchecked.

The action of disappearing from the first list gives me the correct slideUp() animation, but since there is JavaScript in my backend doing the actual splice and push of the corresponding item in the array, the slideDown() animation does not register when it appears in the other list.

I hope this is a good enough explanation. Here is also a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohithdm/fvfymf0b/) that shows the animation in action, however it is only for one list. I built it for demonstration purposes.

I don't know if this helps but I was wondering if `DOMNodeInserted` was a potential solution.

Comment: There is only 1 list in the Fiddle provided & it seems to be working fine

Comment: Right like i said I can't replicate the items going from one list to another because I can't copy al of the backend code generating the new elements. I just want to know if it's possible to append a slideDown() on every newly created li element.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one template for the `<ul>` rendering one template for each `<li>`:

```
<template name="Items> 
  <ul>
    {{#each items}}
      {{> Item}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="Item">
  <li class="item">{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

**Be carefull with the template names Items and Item (there is an S at the end of the first).**

This way, everytime a `<li>` changes, the Item template is rendered.
Make the slide up animation on Template.Item.events:

```
Template.Item.events({
  'click .item'() {
    // Slide up
    // Edit your database
  }
});
```

Make the slide down animation on Template.Item.onRendered:

```
Template.Item.onRendered(function (){
  // Slide down
});
```

Comment: Ok awesome! I'm very excited because this is how it is kind of set up right now.

I have a tempalte for each of the li's. Could you tell me how exactly I add the slideDown() inside of the onRendered in the li template?

Comment: I'm just unsure of what the actual syntax is for adding the slideDown() to the li element.

Comment: Maybe `this.$('.item').slideDown(300)` ?